# How to use wordpress as blog as a subdirectory for my rails app?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

my_site = http://example.com

my_wordpress_app = http://mywordpressapp.com

I have a running website `my_site` in ruby on rails framework and a running blog `my_wordpress_app` on wordpress.

I'm looking to implement `my_site/blog`(mainly for seo purposes) for blogs and power it with Wordpress CMS. In simple words, when i hit url (`my_site/blog`), my wordpress blog url (`my_wordpress_app`) contents should show up.

What I tried:

- Tried redirecting to `my_wordpress_app` app from application server, but that changes the url in the address bar to wordpress url.
- Read a documentation on rewrite rule at nginx level but I guess that also changes url to wordpress url.

I'm new to wordpress world, Is there a way I could keep `mysite/blog` url  in the address bar and have my wordpress app contents on this page with a CMS powered by Wordpress.

Any clue/direction on how to start will be appreciated.

Comment: move your wordpress to the same domain

Comment: Why don't you want to go with `blog.[my_site]' url rather then '[my_site]/blog'?

Comment: `blog.[my_site]' url rather then '[my_site]/blog' == because of  seo purposes